# how to make the webpack 5.x src path is the project real src path not the webpack config file root path

Tags: typescript, webpack-5

I am config the webpack src path in config like this:

```
'@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
```

seems the webpack did not found the real project src path. the source path was the web pack config path. Now I get the path like this:

```
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/resource/config/src/model/message/MessageType.ts
```

what I really want path is this:

```
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarf-translate-plugin/src/model/message/MessageType.ts
```

what should I do to make the webpack always get the project src path? not the config file itself path.

Answer (score 0):

Tweak the path alias like this to fix it:

```
'@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../src'),
```